# What is the value of 'this' Inside subscribe function of RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Trying to show a popup after routing event I'm facing this issues :

- the angular routing event is firing many times after one `routerLink` click, so I open many popup .
- To resolve the first problem I created a boolean to check if it is the first event.
  But when I try to change the boolean after the first routing events call it always take the same value in events following. 
  My question is :  is the value of `this` in `subscribe` Method a copy of my component ?, otherwise  what can cause this issue and how can I solve it.
  thanks a lot.

Code :

```
@Component({
template ='<a routerLink ="/something" >' 
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

    firstcall : boolean = true;
    constructor(private _router : Router){
        this._router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart && something)
        .subscribe( (event) => {
            if(this.firstcall) {
                this.showPopup()
                this.firstcall=false
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

### Update

even with  `this._router.events.distinct(event => event['url']).subscribe` not working

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable of "this" (of the class) before the subscribe call and use that variable inside subscribe, else it use the "this" instance of the subscribe method.

Try this,

```
@Component({
template ='<a routerLink ="/something" >' 
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

    firstcall : boolean = true;
    that : any = this;
    constructor(private _router : Router){
        this._router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart && something)
        .subscribe( (event) => {
            if(that.firstcall) {
                that.showPopup()
                that.firstcall=false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please add details about what you've changed, and why, don't just answer with a block of code

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but that is'nt known inside subscribe function.

Comment: Not really worthy of a downvote IMO. This answer was what I needed.